# Counting the element cell in a table not in the whole file. Can't find the error in my code

Tags: c#, mvvm

My code counts cells inside a table. I can't find out why my code is counting all the cells in the file, instead of checking it table per table in the file. Below is my code.

```
public void CheckCellCountPerTableRow()
        {
            foreach (var table in _xdoc.Descendants("text").Descendants("table"))
            {
                var constantcellcount = true;
                if (!table.IsEmpty)
                {
                    var cellcount = table.Element("row").Elements("cell").Count();
                    foreach (var row in table.Elements("row"))
                    {
                        var ctr = 0;
                        foreach (var cell in row.Elements("cell"))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ctr = ctr + int.Parse(cell.Attribute("cols").Value);
                            }
                            catch (NullReferenceException nullReferenceException)
                            {
                                ctr++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (cellcount != ctr)
                        {
                            constantcellcount = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!constantcellcount)
                {
                    var errorlist = Errorlist;
                    var errorModel = new ErrorModel
                    {
                        LineNumber = ((IXmlLineInfo) table).LineNumber,
                        ErrorMessage = "Unequal number of cell distribution in the table",
                        Text = Regex.Match(Regex.Replace(table.ToString(), @"\r\n", ""), "<row>.*?</row>", RegexOptions.Singleline).Value.Replace(" />", "/>")
                    };
                    errorlist.Add(errorModel);
                }
            }
        }
```

Below is my xml tag.

```
<p>
    <table>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell>90</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell cols="2"/>
            <cell/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell>11</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
</p>
<p>blah blah blah</p>
<p>
    <table>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell>90</cell>
            <cell/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell>90</cell>
            <cell>90</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell cols="3"/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell>90</cell>
            <cell/>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>blah</cell>
            <cell>11</cell>
            <cell>90</cell>
        </row>
    </table>
</p>
```

1st table consist of 2 cell in each row, and the 2nd table consist of 3 table, this xml tag flagged as error which is not correct, the checking of cell count in every should be table per table () and not in whole file. I am wondering what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Show your XML, at least.

Comment: if there are 5 tables in the files, the program check the cell count of 5 table as whole table and table per table. Sample is that if my 1st table contains 8 cell in every row, and my 2nd table is contains 5 cell in every row my code above flagged this as error. which is not correct checking of count of cell should be table per table. what is wrong with my code.

Comment: It is not your XML...This description gives nothing.

Comment: here.. in my new sample. there are 2 cell in every row in the first table and 3 cell in the second table. my code flagged this as error. what I want here.. table per table checking

Comment: It looks good. Your `errorlist` should contain from 0 to 2 messages, based on the input. What is the expected output?

Comment: my goal here for my code, is to check cell count in every table, but I notice that if my table in my file is more than 1, my code treat the 2nd table as part of the first table. How can I prevent this to happen? so my my checking will be table per table? my expected output here <row>
            <cell cols="2"/>
            <cell/>
        </row>
is the only error here. but what happens, is it errors also my second table which should be separated from the 1st table

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, have you check what is wrong with my code, I used foreach so checking will table per table, but it this not the result that I want.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, still I can't find my error in my code? I used foreach in filter the tag table,  by getting all table as descendants. my expected output is that only the first table should flagged as error, but still the second it flagged as error.. don't know what happen.